# Extract Url of Hosted Javascript File

Tags: javascript

I have an external JavaScript file that is stored at: http://example.com/script.js. I'd like to extract out http://example.com from inside the JavaScript file. The only problem is that I'm embedding the JavaScript file in a website with a different domain. I've looked into using `window.location` but that will return the url of the page that has embedded the JavaScript instead of the url that's hosting the script.

**example.com/script.js**

```
var hostingUrl = window.location.origin;
alert(hostingUrl);
```

**anotherdomain.com**

```
<!-- This will alert: 'anotherdomain.com' instead of: 'example.com' -->
<script src="http://example.com/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: `alert(document.currentScript.src)` for older browsers, and not using `async` or `defer` attribs on the <script> tag, `alert(document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1])`, or the equivalent dom methods/$ to fetch all script tags (then take the last one). watch out for people re-hosting the file under a different name, and redirects.

Comment: Heads up, document.currentScript is not supported in IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript

Comment: can you control the `script src...` code? Then you could use `<script id='myScript' src='://example.com'` and access the `<script>`s src attribute via dom (`document.getElementByID('myScript').src`)

Comment: @tillz: that won't work with `require()`-type solutions, but should work otherwise.

Comment: @tillz I had thought about doing something like that but I was curious if there was a way to do it completely from within the JavaScript file. Thanks @dandavis & @SavWebDeveloper. `document.currentScript` would be perfect in a no-IE world :(

Comment: check that out. apparently you can't do that http://stackoverflow.com/a/14161737/4810628